# how to connect Django project to mongoDB?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo, djongo

i have django project where its connected to the default sqlite3 database
i want to change the database to the mongoDB  but its not working i am using the below packages

## settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': '3DHologram',
        'ENFORCE_SCHEMA': False,
        'CLIENT': {
            'host': 'mongodb+srv://testdevleb:JmqUI7qNMB4hvfil@cluster0.dofcak0.mongodb.net/3DHologram?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
            'username': 'testdevleb',
            'password': 'JdcdUI7kNMB4hvfil',
            'authMechanism': 'SCRAM-SHA-1',
            'authSource': 'admin',
        }
    }
}
```

## packages:

- Django==4.1.13
- djongo==1.2.3
- dnspython==2.4.2
- pymongo==3.10.1
- pytz==2023.3.post1

once i try  the below command

```
python manage.py migrate
```

error:

> File
> "F:\private_projects\videoproject\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py",
> line 126, in load_backend
> raise ImproperlyConfigured( django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'djongo' isn't an
> available database backend or couldn't be imported. Check the above
> exception. To use one of the built-in backends, use
> 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
> 'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'